# PyQT5 Anaconda installation - packages not taken in to account

Tags: python, anaconda, pyqt5

I have tried to install pyqt5 in Conda in several ways, lately this way:

```
pip3 install pyqt5==5.12.0
```

However, ain any case I receive an error like that which I cannot solve, also when installing newer versions of pyqt5:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
spyder 4.1.5 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
```

My packages look like:

```
# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pyqt5                     5.12                     pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5-sip                 4.19.19                  pypi_0    pypi
```

Any idea what I have to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I have Python 3.8, but PyQt5 is only feasiable with Python 3.4. Installing PyQt6 solved the problem.